# Conflict PhpMyAdmin + Plesk 11

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, root, plesk, database-administration

I'm a server admin.

I manage my server with Plesk 11 which include phpmyadmin installation by default.

I want to install a custom phpmyadmin to manage my mysql databases without need of Plesk.

What I wonder to know, if there will be a conflict after this operation.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no any conflicts. Plesk ships phpMyAdmin in separate package psa-phpmyadmin, install it in /usr/local/psa folder and plesk don't know about any other phpMyAdmin installation.

Comment: Thank you very much, That was all what I need to hear :)